# can't mount /dev/vg00/var

Tags: mount

I'm trying to access data on a hard drive using a rescue system.  I've mounted the root partition as so:

```
mount /dev/md1 /mnt
```

If I do

```
cat /mnt/etc/fstab
```

I see

```
/dev/vg00/var  /var     xfs
```

So I tried:

```
mount /dev/vg00/usr /mnt/usr/
```

But I get the error message:

> mount: special device /dev/vg00/usr does not exist

Why does it say that the device doesn't exist if it exists?

Comment: I love you guys, it works!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
pvscan
vgscan
vgchange -a y
```

And after that try mounting again.

Comment: I only can mark this answer like correct. Can't vote you up because people vote -1 my questions :( sorry and thanks!!!!

Comment: 4 rep more and i can vote you up! jaja

Answer (score 1):

What makes you believe that the device exists?  Entries in fstab don't create devices; devices create devices.  Given that you're running a rescue system, I would expect that it's a fairly shite one which doesn't automatically scan for and activate volume groups.  Try running `pvscan; vgchange -ay` and see if your LVs magically reappear.

Comment: I think the device exists because if i do: mount /dev/md1 /mnt i could chroot /mnt and see my folders but /home neither /var but i'll try

Comment: What does that have to do with whether or not `/dev/vg00/var` exists?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i read the other answer before yours but i see now that you answered first, how could it be possible?

Comment: Because I'm a faster typist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your running a combination of software raid (mdadm) and volume groups on a linux machine.

In your case the problem looks to be related to your raid manager not detecting and creating the raid volume, or the volume manager not detecting and creating.

This link has an extensive guide how to repair volume groups within software raids:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8874

Comment: I'll try the 3 commands that i saw below, and if doesn't work, i'll read that document. Added to bookmarks btw. Thanks.